# Why does GlobIterator produce a different output than the glob function?

Tags: php, spl

I'm trying to use the [GlobIterator class](http://php.net/GlobIterator).

I am using the same PATTERN as in the [glob function](http://php.net/glob), but the GlobIterator produces an empty array.

Example:

```
$glob = glob('./*');
print_r($glob);
```

will give me an array of all files in the current directory.

But when I do

```
$glob = new GlobIterator('./*');
print_r(iterator_to_array($glob));
```

The result is just `Array()` with no items in the array.

Can someone tell me why this happens?

I have tested this on Windows 8 / Apache 2 / PHP 5.3.

Apparently, [this works from CLI](http://eval.in/22190) and also on Linux.

Maybe it's a bug with the Apache SAPI on Windows?

Comment: Try to use `__DIR__ . '/*'` instead of `'./*'`. If that still fails, it might have to do with https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55701.

Answer (score 3):

**Introduction**

According to the [PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php), `glob` and `GlobIterator` initial parameter is totally different. Its not clear why this is so but its was clearly stated.

[glob](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

```
 array [glob][3] ( string $pattern [, int $flags = 0 ] )
                              ^
                              |--- Expects pattern
```

[GlobIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/globiterator.construct.php)

```
public [GlobIterator::__construct][5] ( string $path [, int $flags = FilesystemIterator::KEY_AS_PATHNAME | FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_FILEINFO ] )
                                                 ^
                                                 |--- Expects Path
```

**The Solution**

Always use `full path`. Have see this error a couple of times but if you use full path you can be assure they would both return the same file list

**Example without full path**

```
$path = "./test";
$glob1 = glob($path . '/*');
print_r($glob1);

$glob2 = new GlobIterator($path . '/*');
print_r(iterator_to_array($glob2));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => ./test/fake.png
    [1] => ./test/php-logo-virus.jpg
    [2] => ./test/save
    [3] => ./test/test.png
)
Array
(
)
```

**Example with Full Path**

```
$path = __DIR__ ."/test";
$glob1 = glob($path . '/*');
print_r($glob1);

$glob2 = new GlobIterator($path . '/*');
print_r(iterator_to_array($glob2));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => C:\lab\stackoverflow/test/fake.png
    [1] => C:\lab\stackoverflow/test/php-logo-virus.jpg
    [2] => C:\lab\stackoverflow/test/save
    [3] => C:\lab\stackoverflow/test/test.png
)
Array
(
    [C:\lab\stackoverflow/test\fake.png] => SplFileInfo Object
        (
            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => C:\lab\stackoverflow/test\fake.png
            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => fake.png
        )

    [C:\lab\stackoverflow/test\php-logo-virus.jpg] => SplFileInfo Object
        (
            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => C:\lab\stackoverflow/test\php-logo-virus.jpg
            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => php-logo-virus.jpg
        )

    [C:\lab\stackoverflow/test\save] => SplFileInfo Object
        (
            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => C:\lab\stackoverflow/test\save
            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => save
        )

    [C:\lab\stackoverflow/test\test.png] => SplFileInfo Object
        (
            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => C:\lab\stackoverflow/test\test.png
            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => test.png
        )

)
```

**Output Different Format**

As you can see `$glob1 !== $glob2` not because the files are not present but because `glob` would return a `array with string path` of files while `GlobIterator` would return [`SplFileInfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php) which has its on advantages.

***To get pure array list from `GlobIterator` :***

```
print_r(array_values(array_map("strval",iterator_to_array($glob2))));
```

**Conclusion**

Yes your code would work on any platform so far you do `Unit Testing` and maintain consistency. I don't need to start telling the advantages of `GlobIterator`  or `Iterator` or `glob` but be rest assured when used properly would return same result

Comment: You can also make use of the `CURRENT_AS_PATHNAME` flag if you want to have strings instead of `SplFileInfo`s.